# Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

Why I'm getting this error randomly .,Powershell script sometimes working properly sometime not working throwing below error.

```
    Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while making the HTTP request to 
    https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server 
    certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the 
    security binding between the client and the server.
At D:\O365License\Licensing.ps1:28 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], CommunicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

Comment: Without showing the actual code that throws the error it is impossible to help you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You might be suffering from a .NET related issue with TLS 1.2.  Try running this before you run the `Connect-MsolService` command.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```